# Problema con apk firmada android

Tags: android

Me ha surgido un problema, cuando genero un Apk firmado para release y lo instalo directamente en el dispositivo este no me conecta con los servicios rest de mi servidor, pero si genero al apk firmada en debug si me conecta sin problemas, y si lo instalado en android studio igual no tengo ningún problema, ¿alguien sabrá algo sobre esto?

Mi archivo de configuración:

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0'
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta2'

    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
 belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-
      releases/raw/master/"
     }
   }
 }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
 }

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

    minSdkVersion = 14
    targetSdkVersion = 23

   sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
   targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

   lintAbortOnError = false

// QuickBlox SDK version
qbSdkVersion = '2.6.1'

versionName = "2.6.1"

testRunnerVersion = "0.4.1"


// Dependency versions
playServicesVersion = '8.4.0'
//playServicesVersion = '9.0.2'
supportV4Version = '23.1.1'
appcompatV7Version = '23.1.1'
recyclerviewV7Version = '23.2.1'
supportAnnotationsVersion = '23.1.1'
designVersion = '23.1.1'

uilVersion = '1.9.0'
glideVersion = '3.6.1'
pullToRefreshVersion = '3.2.3'
stickyListHeaders = '2.7.0'
robotoTextViewVersion = '2.4.3'
stickersVersion = '0.7.3'
crashlyticsVersion = '2.2.2'
}


def makeJar(variant, project) {
//empty
 }
```

build.gradle del modulo

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
//buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "cibanco.com.mx.bcp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 9
    versionName "3.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

flavorDimensions "tier"
productFlavors {
    free {
        dimension "tier"
    }

    full {
        dimension "tier"
    }
   }
 }

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'

//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'

//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'

compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion")
compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion")
compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion")

compile project(path: ':sample-core')

//compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:${rootProject.playServicesVersion}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${rootProject.playServicesVersion}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${rootProject.playServicesVersion}"
compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${rootProject.glideVersion}"
compile "se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:${rootProject.stickyListHeaders}"

//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'

/*
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
*/
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'

//compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.16@aar"

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.2@aar'
compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  }

 //apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle sample core

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
   buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
  }

  dependencies {
    compile ("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-
    messages:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion" )

     compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${rootProject.playServicesVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.designVersion}"
compile "com.github.johnkil.android-
 robototextview:robototextview:${rootProject.robotoTextViewVersion}"

}
```

Manifiest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission
    android:name="cibanco.com.mx.bcp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="cibanco.com.mx.bcp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> -->



    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="editada" />
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="editada" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.OlvidoPass"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.EstadoOperacionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_estado_operacion"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />



    <activity
        android:name=".activity.NotificacionesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activity.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/login_title"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activity.SelectUsersActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activity.DialogsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activity.ChatActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/ChatActivityTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activity.ChatInfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/chat_info"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activity.AttachmentImageActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="cibanco.com.mx.bcp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.gcm.GcmPushListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.gcm.GcmPushInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.RHMenuCapacitacion"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rhmenu_capacitacion"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

</application>
```

Comment: El problema podría estar en el `Manifest`. ¿Puedes mostrarlo [editando tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/116963/edit)?

Comment: Listo agregue el manifiest, le quite algunas actividades para acortarlo

Comment: Quita las API KEY que aparezcan, es información confidencial...

Comment: En el archivo build.gradle del módulo, en la zona de buildTypes añade  debug {
            debuggable true
        } al mismo nivel que release{...}

Comment: Lo que te dice @PabloSimonDiEstefano, o bien en el `Manifest` en la parte donde están los `user-permission` pon esto: **`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
     android:debuggable="true"`**

Comment: Gracias, ya hice una prueba con ambas opciones pero sigue sin poder conectarse a los servicios en el apk release

Comment: ¿El servicio REST al que te conectas trabaja con certificados o con algún otro tipo de validación que estés omitiendo?

Comment: @RogelioSanchez para usar el REST, obtuviste una API key? si es así platícanos como la obtuviste.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, no,  los servicios no necesitan nada en especial para ser llamados, los llamo sin problema desde RestClient de google, soap ui, incluso desde la misma aplicación cuando la ejecuto en el emulador o instalo el apk directamente de android studio

Comment: He estado pensando, sobre actualizar algunas librerias, algunos consejos sobre como mejorar el gradle ? , puede que me falte actualizar algo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione deshabilitando de optimización, aunque no me parece algo muy optimo. Aunque ahora ya se conecta sin problemas.

```
    buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }


  }
```